# Why does resque-scheduler try to run a scheduled-job that no longer exists?

Tags: resque, resque-scheduler

Why does resque-scheduler try to run a job that used to exist, but no longer does?

I used to have an old resque-scheduler job a few weeks ago, but have removed it:

```
EmailRelevantQuestions:
  every: 15m
  class: EmailRelevantQuestions
  queue: email_queue
  description: "Iterates through users and emails them relevant questions."
```

But for some reason this job is still firing every 15 minutes, and the class no longer exists in my codebase, or my scheduler?? My logs state:

```
2013-09-18 15:18:42.267177+00:00 app scheduler.1 - - 2013-09-18 10:18:42 queueing EmailRelevantQuestions (EmailRelevantQuestions)
2013-09-18 15:18:42.600357+00:00 app scheduler.1 - - 2013-09-18 10:18:42 queueing FrequentWorker (FrequentWorker)
2013-09-18 15:18:43.817671+00:00 app resque.1  - - *** Checking daily_queue
2013-09-18 15:18:43.820166+00:00 app resque.1  - - *** Checking email_queue
2013-09-18 15:18:43.826799+00:00 app resque.1  - - *** Found job on email_queue
2013-09-18 15:18:43.826914+00:00 app resque.1  - - *** got: (Job{email_queue} | EmailRelevantQuestions | [])
2013-09-18 15:18:43.832159+00:00 app resque.1  - - *** resque-1.25.0: Processing email_queue since 1379517523 [No Name]
2013-09-18 15:18:43.933346+00:00 app resque.1  - - *** Running after_fork hooks with [(Job{email_queue} | EmailRelevantQuestions | [])]
2013-09-18 15:18:43.944943+00:00 app resque.1  - - *** (Job{email_queue} | EmailRelevantQuestions | []) ***FAILED***: #<NameError: uninitialized constant EmailRelevantQuestions>
```

Is there some sort of cache?

ps. I recently updated my resque form 1.24 to 1.25...not sure if this caused the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this was causing old jobs to come up from past creation:

```
Resque::Scheduler.dynamic = true
```